# Add space between table and text

Tags: errors

I'm trying to add some space between my table and the text but the command `\setlength{\textfloatsep}{2cm}` is not working ¿What is the problem?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption}
\begin{document}
\section{PLAN DE TRABAJO Y CRONOGRAMA DE ACTIVIDADES}
\vspace{2cm}
El plan de trabajo estará fundamentado en la resolución secuencial de cada uno de los objetivos específicos planteados con anterioridad. Se estima una duración total de entre 16 semanas y se espera dedicar en general un  total de 2 a 4 semanas por objetivo. El plan de trabajo se ilustra en la tabla 1. 
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{2cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X | X |}
  \hline
   \textbf{Objetivo especifico}     & \textbf{Metas}     & \textbf{Indicador}       &\textbf{Actividades}     \\ \hline
   0         & 2        & 4         &6         \\ \hline
   1         & 3        & 5         &7         \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\captionof{table}{Plan de trabajo} \label{tab:title2} 
\end{document}
```

And this is my output:

[image]

I'm using Texmaker on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `\tabularx` isn't a float. So your commands don't work. Enclose `tabularx` inside `table` an use `\renewcommand{\intextsep}{2cm}`. Or put the `\captionof` above `tabularx` and use `\captionsetup{aboveskip=2cm}`. If you don't want to uae `table` just try putting a blank line before `tabularx` and use `\vspace{2cm}`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you my friend! Im gonna try it

Comment: @HarishKumar make it an answer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Hi David Congrats on 300K. :) Good going. Answer added. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

`tabularx` is not a float and the commands you are using don't work there (they work with floats like `table`). You have following options:

Enclose `tabularx` inside `table` environment and use `\renewcommand{\intextsep}{2cm}`. In this case you won't need `\captionof` but `\caption` will suffice. Or

Put the `\captionof` above `tabularx` and use `\captionsetup{aboveskip=2cm}` or

Put a blank line before `\begin{tabularx}` followed by `\vspace{2cm}` like

```
El plan de trabajo estará fundamentado en la resolución secuencial de cada uno de los objetivos específicos planteados con anterioridad. Se estima una duración total de entre 16 semanas y se espera dedicar en general un  total de 2 a 4 semanas por objetivo. El plan de trabajo se ilustra en la tabla 1. 

\vspace{2cm}  %% 2cm is changeable as your wish
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X | X |}
```